# Why does the first iteration of update query run quickly and then subsequent iterations slow down significantly?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a fairly simple function that performs a single update query:

```
def update_belgarath_match(dal, match_row):
    belgarath_match_id = match_row["id_"]
    update_match = dal.session.query(Match.id_)
    update_match = update_match.filter(Match.id_.__eq__(belgarath_match_id))
    update_match.update(match_row)
```

I apply this function as I scrape a website and convert the data into `match_row`. I then run a `commit` at the end of the process which was usually very quick for a few hundred records.

However, I recently had to scrape a few thousand pages and so I added a `commit` at the end of the function to make sure each record was saved in the database as it was scraped:

```
def update_belgarath_match(dal, match_row):
    belgarath_match_id = match_row["id_"]
    update_match = dal.session.query(Match.id_)
    update_match = update_match.filter(Match.id_.__eq__(belgarath_match_id))
    update_match.update(match_row)
    dal.session.commit()
```

The function now takes a fraction of a second to run on the first iteration but then slows down to 40 seconds for the second iteration and beyond:

```
2020-09-20 16:15:36 - Adding post match data
Finished 'update_belgarath_match' in 0.2861 secs
1 out of 14820 - https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/thailand/bangkok-challenger-men-2010/nielsen-frederik-gojowczyk-peter-WfStAx89/
Finished 'update_belgarath_match' in 40.2469 secs
2 out of 14820 - https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/thailand/bangkok-challenger-men-2010/kudryavtsev-alexander-soeda-go-0Km17zhS/
Finished 'update_belgarath_match' in 40.2809 secs
3 out of 14820 - https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/thailand/bangkok-challenger-men-2010/ward-james-rieschick-sebastian-YFS1001K/
Finished 'update_belgarath_match' in 40.7082 secs
```

Timing a few things it appears that as soon as I make the first `commit` then every subsequent `update_match.update(match_row)` takes 40 seconds. Weirdly when I left it running for about 30 minutes it broke itself out of the delay and started iterating at a fraction of a second again. I haven't been able to replicate this again though.

I've tried only committing every X records and the function runs quickly for the X records and then takes around 40 seconds to commit the changes. Pretty sure it shouldn't take that long!!

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

---

**Edit:**

As requested in comments:

```
'match_', 'CREATE TABLE `match_` (\n  
`id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  
`date_time_scheduled` datetime DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`date_time_actual` datetime DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`tour_id` int NOT NULL,\n  
`tournament_id` int NOT NULL,\n  
`tours_ID_T` int NOT NULL,\n  
`rounds_ID_R` int NOT NULL,\n  
`today_players_ID1` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`today_players_ID2` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`games_players_ID1` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`games_players_ID2` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`uncertainty_bin` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`p1_win_pred_ogion` float DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`p1_win_pred_rf_ogion` float DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`p1_win_pred_ged` float DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`p1_win_pred_rf_ged` float DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`winning_player` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`completed_sets` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`result_type_id` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`p1_pinnacle_closing_odds` float DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`p2_pinnacle_closing_odds` float DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`post_match_data_retrieved` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n  
`created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n  
PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__tours_ID_T` (`tours_ID_T`),\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__today_players_ID1` (`today_players_ID1`),\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__games_players_ID1` (`games_players_ID1`),\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__tour_id` (`tour_id`),\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__rounds_ID_R` (`rounds_ID_R`),\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__today_players_ID2` (`today_players_ID2`),\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__games_players_ID2` (`games_players_ID2`),\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__uncertainty_bin` (`uncertainty_bin`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__tournament_id` (`tournament_id`)\n
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2820046 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

Comment: It would help to see DDL for the underlying table.  Including any indexes.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - thanks for responding - how would I get this for you?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: Hey. Added in ```SHOW CREATE TABLE <table-name>;``` which I think should give you everything? There are about 1.4 million rows.

Comment: I think I may have found the issue inadvertently. I recently changed the looping function that generates the dictionaries to source some of the data from an SQLAlchemy query rather than a list previously. I've just switched that back and everything works as before. Could my issue be related to having the 'generating' query 'live' when I'm also trying to update the database?